# Get the class of all form elements using jQuery for form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am working on form validation, and the submit button is disabled by default. If all of the inputs have the class 'valid' I want to enable the submit button.

I have tried this code but it does not work.

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).on('input', function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('valid') {
            // All the classes are valid.
            alert('Form is valid.');
        }
    });
});
```

Also, if there are multiple forms on the page, how can I assure that the jQuery is only looking inside that form for the valid class. One form with all valid classes should not enable the submit buttons on all forms.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt395/1/) of the problem.

Comment: Remove the line `$(this).on...` useless. Missing `)` in `.hasClass('valid'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : I updated [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4RLc/2/), and added checks on every `keyup` event on your fields. The function ignores the submit button of course.

---

Old answer :

you can try this code :

```
function checkForm() {
  var valid = true;
  $('input','#myForm').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('valid') {
            valid = false;
        }
  });
  return valid;
}
```

Comment: I want to check for the valid class in realtime, not just at the end, is that possible?

Comment: The submit button is clickable when there is an invalid email.

Comment: I thought you just wanted the "class check" part. Here it is full : http://jsfiddle.net/w4RLc/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this updated jsfiddle.  Basically, you need to keep track of which fields are currently invalid, so I added the class invalid to each input initially.  In your code when a valid email is entered, it then returns a list of all fields with the invalid class.  If the length of that list is 0, then I remove the disabled attribute from the submit button.

```
    var invalidFields = $('.invalid');
    if(invalidFields.length === 0) {    
        $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tt395/4/

Comment: Best solution so far, but I do not want to alarm the user with invalid class before they have done anything. Is there a work around for that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gg92v/2/

Shortly, check your form like this:

```
if($('#form1 input:not(.valid)').length == 0){
    $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled',false)
}
```

Comment: The link is bad, it is to a previous version.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: The submit button is not clickable when there are valid email addresses.